# PostGIS ST_Difference is returning overlapped areas

Tags: postgis, st-difference

I´m using this SQL sentence to obtain the difference of two layers, exactly I understood that ST_Difference does, that is, it should return polygons that don´t overlap and the not overlapped area when two polygons partially overlap.

```
create table fitofisionomia_areas_antropizadas_5880_fix_biomass_eba as
select a.fid, st_difference(a.geom,b.geom) as geom
from fitofisionomia a
inner  join fitofisionomia_areas_naturais_5880_fix_biomass_eba b
on st_difference(a.geom,b.geom) is not null
```

This is a portion of layer a:
[image: This is a portion of layer a]
Add layer b...
[image: Layer b...]
Then the difference
[image: Then the difference]

As I´m just testing I´m using LIMIT, so maybe some "holes" were not identified, however, this big yellow polygon is an overlapped area. That´s the problem.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about your layer a, b and c? the lines are confusing that not sure which part is your actual polygon

Comment: Layer "a" is the basic layer, that is, I need the polygons from layer "b" that doesn´t cover any polygon of layer "a". Layer "c" is the difference I´ve got after run the sentence. So, I didn´t expect the yellow polygon, because the area below it is part of "a" and "b", as you can see in the figures.

Comment: Select b.fid too. Analize a.fid and b.fid for that difference feature. Are they overlapped polygons?